# Python why do my nested functions give a Nonetype error?

Tags: python, callable, nonetype

I'm new to programming.

```
 def start():
      x = 4
      def addition():
          n = 3
          def exponential():
              z = 2
              def multiplication():
                  l = 2
                  print(x + n ** z * l)
              return multiplication

  equals = start()
  equals()
```

why am I getting a "Nonetype" object is not callable error?

Comment: `start` doesn't return anything. It defines a local variable `x` with value `4`, and a local function `addition`. It looks like you meant to return `addition` from `start` (and not return `multiplication` at all)?

Comment: You're only returning something from the `exponential` function.  Your functions `start`, `addition`, and `multiplication` don't return anything.  What are you trying accomplish here?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing a bunch of programming concepts:

- Don't declare a function whenever you only need a statement
- You're confusing function declaration with function call (invocation), and also the nesting is pointless. Declaring nested fn2 inside of fn1 doesn't magically also call fn2 and also transmit its return-value back to fn1. You still have to use an explicit return-statement from each fn.(If you forget that, you're implicitly returning None, which is almost surely not what you want)
- For now, just don't ever nest functions at all.
- Functions with no arguments are essentially useless, they can't take inputs and compute a result. Figure out what their arguments should be.

Specifically for the code you posted, addition(), multiplication() don't have any return value at all, i.e. None. exponential() returns multiplication, i.e. a function which only returns None. But then, both addition() and start() ignore that anyway, since they don't have a return-statement either, hence they implicitly return None.
Calling start() just gives you None, so you're just assigning `equals = None`. Not the result of some mathematical expression like you intended.

So:

- reduce every unnecessary function to just a statement
- declare each of your functions separately (non-nested)
- each fn must have args (in this case at least two args, to make any sense)
- each fn must have a return statement returning some value
- only declaring a function and never calling it means it never gets run.
- put an empty line in between function declarations (Then it's obvious if you forgot the return-statement)

Answer (score 0):

Credits goes to @BrenBarn for being first to answer this. But I wanna post the code to make it more clear, and point out to some ways to make it better.

```
def start():
  x = 4
  def addition():
    n = 3
    def exponential():
      z = 2
      def multiplication():
        l = 2
        print (x + n ** z * l)

      return multiplication()
    return exponential()
  return addition()

equals = start()
print equals #Output: 22
```

However, this is not the best way to list different methods. You should learn how to use a class in your python code.

I am going to define a class called "mathOperations". I will define three methods (functions): addition,exponential, multiplication. These functions are reusable.

```
class mathOperations():
  def addition(self,x,y):
    return x+y
  def exponential(self,x,y):
    return x**y
  def multiplication(self,x,y):
    return x*y

m= mathOperations()
z=2
l=2
x=4
n=3

result= m.addition(x,m.multiplication(m.exponential(n,z),l))
print result #Output:22
```

You should learn how to make your code reusable, try to google "procedural programming"; "Oriented Object Programming", or check "Learn Python the hard way" book. These are first and most used approach to make your code reusable. Think of it like a generic mathematical function to solve problems.

Comment: `mathOperations` does not need to be a class (just a file or package), since it has no members, stores no state, and all its methods are just functions (`self` is never used), and strictly are only classmethods.

Comment: @smci: +1, right! I just want to point out the use of class in packaging different methods as it seems that he's thinking this way (How to package my code), but that's right, this is not perfect use of using OOP.

Comment: It's not OOP at all. There is no 'object' here at all. They're just wrestling with misunderstanding the basic difference between declaring and calling a function, needing args and return-values.